# PHP / HTML post not working as expected

Tags: php, html, forms, input, currency

I am pretty new to PHP and working on a small currency converter page for practice. My PHP and HTML code is all in one page called "index.php":

```
<?php 
$originalAmount = $_POST["originalAmount"];
$convertedAmount = 0.00;
$currency1 = $_POST["currency1"];
$currency2 = $_POST["currency2"];
function convertCurrency($input, $origCurr, $convertCurr) {

    if ($origCurr === 1){
        if ($convertCurr === 2){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 0.78;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        elseif ($convertCurr === 3){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 0.90;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        else {
            $convertedAmount = $input;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
    }

    if ($origCurr === 2){
        if ($convertCurr === 1){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 1.29;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        elseif ($convertCurr === 3){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 1.16;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        else {
            $convertedAmount = $input;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
    }

    if ($origCurr === 3){
        if ($convertCurr === 2){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 0.86;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        elseif ($convertCurr === 1){
            $convertedAmount = $input * 1.11;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
        else {
            $convertedAmount = $input;
            return $convertedAmount;
        }
    }
}

$convertedAmount = convertCurrency($originalAmount, $currency1, $currency2);
?>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Currency Converter</title>

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Bootstrap 3-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Custom CSS-->
    <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--Header Row-->
        <div class="row page-header">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Currenccy Converter</h1></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>Add items via the input below.
                    <br>Click to mark complete (Completed Items will be marked with a green background.)
                    <br>To delete a task, Click on the X.
                    <br>Double Click to edit the item, it will be moved to the add item box</p>

            </div>

        </div>


        <!--Add Task / Input Row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 well">
                <h2 class="text-xs-center"><?php print $convertedAmount; ?></h2>
                <form class="form-control" id="converterForm" action="index.php" method="post">        

                    <select name="currency1" id="currency1">
                        <option value="zzz">Starting</option>
                        <option value="1">USD</option>
                        <option value="2">GBP</option>
                        <option value="3">EUR</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="currency2" id="currency2">
                        <option value="zzz">Converted</option>
                        <option value="1">USD</option>
                        <option value="2">GBP</option>
                        <option value="3">EUR</option>
                    </select>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="originalAmount" id="origLabel">Amount:</label>
                        <input id="originalAmount" type="number" value="0.00" name="originalAmount">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

My problem is, that it seemingly does not run on the server. I used to have a readonly input that I was trying to update via php `echo` as the value, but when I clicked submit, it did not work. I then replaced the input with an H2 element that contains the `echo`.

My goals for this page were to complete all actions via HTML and PHP without the aid of javascript / ajax.

Is there any super apparent reason to why the `echo` in a value wouldn't return the value of `$converted`? I'd rather use the readonly input and style that with CSS than use an H2 element, but either will work I suppose.

Looking forward to what you fine folks think. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** You are using `===` in all if conditions, `===` is used to compare value as well as type of the variable. In your case `$_POST['your_variable']` is of string type and you are comparing string with number. `if ($origCurr === 1)`. Read comparison operators [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison)

[image]

**Solution:** Either typecast variable or use `==` to compare only values. `if ($origCurr == 1)`

Comment: Ahh. Yeah I know about the == vs === but I was wrongly assuming that because I used input type number it would pull in an int without converting it. Doh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rohit is spot on with the reason why this error occurs. I would also like to offer this alternative method for the conversion function that would still need to take into account the typing of the input variables.

```php
function convertCurrency($input, $origCurr, $convertCurr) {

    $conversionTable = array(
            '1' => array('2' => 0.78, '3' => 0.9),
            '2' => array('1' => 1.29, '3' => 1.16),
            '3' => array('2' => 0.86, '1' => 1.11)
        );

        return $input * (($origCurr !== $convertCurr) ? $conversionTable[$origCurr][$convertCurr] : 1);
}
```

Comment: Good alternative, I think you missed 3rd case? `USD <=> USD`

Comment: @Rohit true! I have updated the function to reflect case when `$origCurr == $converCurr`

Comment: Why it should return 1 ? It should be input value `return ($origCurr !== $convertCurr) ? $input * $conversionTable[$origCurr][$convertCurr] : $input;`

Comment: Because that code would cause a currency converted to itself to be multiplied by itself. The code was wrong, it needed another set of parenthesis around it.